# Can anyone help resolve "newSensor_AllFramesReady does not exist in current context" using Kinect and C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sdk, kinect

I am following the channel9 tutorial on setting up the development environment for the Kinect using VS 2010 C# and the Kinect SDK. I did everything Dan said but when i typed in:

```
        if (newSensor == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        //register for event and enable Kinect features you want
        newSensor.AllFramesReady += new EventHandler<AllFramesReadyEventArgs>(newSensor_AllFramesReady);
        newSensor.ColorStream.Enable(ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);
        newSensor.DepthStream.Enable(DepthImageFormat.Resolution640x480Fps30);
        newSensor.SkeletonStream.Enable();
```

and pressed F5 it came up with the error The name newSensor_AllFramesReady does not exist in current context.

Im pretty sure I followed everything properly in the tutorial, and looking around on google everyone else seems to use this name just fine.

Can anyone please help me fix this problem?? I am new at C# and am trying to get my head around it all in time for my final degree piece deadline in 6 weeks! Your help is VERY much appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to subscribe to an event by specifying an event handler that does not exist.

This event handler, in the form of a method generally (though you can do this with anonymous delegated and so on) must be present, and match the signature defined by the event. It should probably look something like this:

```
void newSensor_AllFramesReady(object sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs e) 
{
    //code that does something as a 'reaction' to the event being fired.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, you're totally right. Just below the code I pasted here I had:

void _sensor_AllFramesReady(object sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)  
{ 

instead of "void newSensor_AllFramesReady" due to a previous step in the tutorial I was watching. I must have missed where he said to change that bit too, but thanks to you I've done it and it works great!

Thank you so much!